# Place buttons side by side dynamically with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Currently I have this code:

```
<div class="button-box col-lg-12">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
</div>
```

While this helps if all I want to display is two buttons, but how can I dynamically make buttons esentially take up 50% of the width of the container for each button?

For example, if I put 4 a tags in the code above,

```
<div class="button-box col-lg-12">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
</div>
```

It would turn out like so,

```
<div class="button-box col-lg-12">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
</div>
<div class="button-box col-lg-12">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
</div>
```

But in one container (button-box)?

Extra CSS I used:

```
.button-box {
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display: flex` on `button-box` div.

```css
.button-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* to wrap the button */
}

.button-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  /* width of the button */
  padding: 0 5px;
  /* to add some spaces between buttons */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* margin for button */
}

.btn-info {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-box col-lg-12">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">About Us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <a href="mylink.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Our Products</a>
  </div>
</div>
```